# special symbols in scss

Tags: webpack, sass, laravel-mix

How to put keyframes into scss?
Code below gives me error. I think because of @

```
@-webkit-keyframes openbt {
  from {
    :before {
      content: '\f0c9';
    }
  }
  to {
    :before {
      content: '\e804';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `Code below gives me error.` and what is the error message?

Comment: It compiles for me.

Comment: here is the link to error details https://yadi.sk/d/M59tgtkQ_9cTjw

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is wrong. You should only use content in @keyframes. In webpack I use postcss and autoprefixer.

If you write in vscode, I recommend stylelint will show you exactly what's wrong with styles.

Below is an example of using the correct @keyframes, content is different but the philosophy is the same;)

**sass:**

```css
.animation:before {
  content: "-";
  animation: openbt 2s;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes openbt {
  from {
    content: "-";
  }
  to {
    content: "x";
  }
}
```

**is converted to:**

```css
.animation:before {
  content: "-";
  -webkit-animation: openbt 2s;
  animation: openbt 2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes openbt {
  from {
    content: "-";
  }
  to {
    content: "x";
  }
}

@keyframes openbt {
  from {
    content: "-";
  }
  to {
    content: "x";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animation">
  Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet...
</div>
```